# How to resolve Selenium Error After installing latest Java version and appium through npm?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, appium-android

I am running my JUnit code from the particular server and this type of weird error I am facing and I have installed latest appium and java version also through npm commands as well but not able to fix this error. Please help to get out of this error.

```
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVpGi.png

     at utils.app_automation.Automation.startApp(Automation.java:196)
                at po.Help.setUP(Help.java:251)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
                at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
                at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
                at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
                at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
                at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
                at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
                at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:94)
                at com.segue.tm.plugins.testlaunch.junit.ju4support.JU4Helper.executeJunitTest(JU4Helper.java:127)
                at com.segue.tm.plugins.testlaunch.junit.ju4support.JU4Helper.executeJU4TestClassOrMethodOnly(JU4Helper.java:53)
                at com.segue.tm.plugins.testlaunch.junit.ju4support.JUnit4CmdLineWrapper.main(JUnit4CmdLineWrapper.java:37).
```

Comment: Please post your stacktrace as text, not as image.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @leoderprofi I have edited my question and please share your answers for this query. Thank You in advance